# how to update the action of form in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can Anybody tell what is missing. I am trying to update the action at run time using javascript ?

I tried a lot but nothing working .

something is gone wrong.

```
  <script> 
    function saveLocation()
     {

     var userType = "<%=request.getParameter("userType")%>";
     if(userType == "EXP" ){
       document.edit_form.action="MeritorEditExpIpTtmAddDelCmd";
     }else if(userType == "WD"){
       document.edit_form.action='MeritorEditShipToCmd';
     }
     document.edit_form.submit();
      return true;
     }
    </script>
    <body>
    <div style="float:left; width:668px;">

    <table width="668" height="274" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;padding:10px; font-family:verdana; font-size:11px;" >
          <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                <form method="get" name="edit_form" id="edit_form_id" action="MeritorEditShipToCmd" >
                <input type="hidden" value="<%=request.getParameter("memberid")%>" name="memberid" />
                <input type="hidden" value="editLocation" name="action" />
                <input type="hidden" value="<%=request.getParameter("shipid")%>" name="shipid" />
                <input type="hidden" value="<%=request.getParameter("addrId")%>" name="addrId" />
                <input type="hidden" value="<%=request.getParameter("userType")%>" name="userType" />

                <Table CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="0" bgcolor="#cdcdfe" style="border:1px solid #999;font-size:11px;" width="400" height="120">

                      <tr>
                            <td>
                            <input type="button" name="save" value="Add/Save Location" onclick="saveLocation()"/>
                            </td>
                      </tr>

                </Table></form>

          </tr>
          </td>
    </table>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I dont know wht is going wrong?

```
 thaxs for the reply.but when I m using the above mentioned help

 <% String userType = request.getParameter("userType"); 
   System.out.println(userType);
   String action = null; 
   if(userType.equals("EXP")){  
   action = "MeritorEditExpIpTtmAddDelCmd"; 
   System.out.println(userType+"hello"+action);}
   else if(userType.equals("WD")){
   System.out.println(userType+"hello");
   action = "MeritorEditShipToCmd"; 
   System.out.println(userType+"hello"+action);}%>

        <form method="get" name="edit_form" id="edit_form_id" action=<%action    %      >>
```

m getting the action as string.but this action is not going to reach my cmdimpl file.
Need Help

Comment: Define `not working`. Also define your scenario. What are you trying to achieve? What is the expected result? What is the actual result? How does the expected result differ than the actual result you are getting? Ask a real question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the action is purely based on a server-side variable, so there's no need at all to be doing this client-side.

```
<%
var userType = request.getParameter("userType");
var action = String.Empty;
if(userType == "EXP")
   action = "MeritorEditExpIpTtmAddDelCmd";
else if(userType == "WD"
   action = "MeritorEditShipToCmd";
%>

<form method="get" name="edit_form" id="edit_form_id" 
     action="<%= action %>" >
```

Comment: i am able to get updated action but it is unable to call controller though when i give in form action directly the controller is called. what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this:

```
<form id="frm" action="#">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('frm').setAttribute('action','http://google.com');
    alert(document.getElementById('frm').getAttribute('action')); //just for test
</script>
```

**See a working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/PCKUx/1/

Make sure you are getting `form` after DOM is ready, so I put the `script` after the form.